# Too many the same code

Tags: java, android

I am newbie in Android and I write my first application, so I have to change a lot of times.

For example:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewByIdtextView 
textView.setText("test");
```

I use it in several places.

In tutorials for Android don't have folders for files. All are in one folder. I can create folder, but are there any guidelines for this?

I can create class Helper and I can get my code with TextView as a method, but what if have I several codes? 
This will break the principle of single class liability, because one method is responsible for TextView and the other for ImageView.

Comment: I create a method and put all of that in there and just call the method in onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Android app still can access any feature of the Java language, which means that you can put different classes into different packages.

Here are some options for organizing your java files: http://guides.codepath.com/android/Organizing-your-Source-Files

If you don't want to call `findViewById()` all the time, you can do this once and store the result in a member variable, or you can use ButterKnife to avoid calling `findViewById()` altogether: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: Can also use Android DataBinding instead of ButterKnife:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: @cRobot true! That does turn on a lot of additional complexity though if all you care about is `findViewById()`. I.e. you can then put logic in your XML files which observers application state.